# send component action to controller emberjs

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli

I'm trying to send an action within a component to a controller. I have a `user.hbs` that contains the component:

```
{{#liquid-if showQuickLaunch}}
    {{quick-launch}}
{{/liquid-if}}  
<div id="userAppWrapper">
    {{user-nav}}
</div>
```

Now the component that holds the action is the `user-nav` component which is right here:

```
<header class="user-main-nav">
    <nav class="user-nav">
        <ul class="list-user-nav">
            <li class="nav-brand">
                <p>Handmade Digital</p>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="list-right-user-nav right">
            <li>
                <p {{action 'showQuickLaunch'}}><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></p>
            </li>
            <li>
                <p>Rodzzlessa <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></p>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
```

as you can see it has the action showQuickLaunch now I want to send that action to the user controller because if you notice on `user.hbs` the first block is an `if` statement to show the `quicklaunch` or not. The property `showQuickLaunch` pertains to the `user controller` not the `nav-component` how can I send that action to the `user controller`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside `user-nav` component you need handle the action `showQuickLaunch` something like:

```
// user-nav.js
Ember.Component.extend({
   actions: {
     showQuickLaunch() {
       this.sendAction();
     }
   }
});
```

[Official Doc](http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.10.0/components/sending-actions-from-components-to-your-application/) explains pretty well and [here](http://jsfiddle.net/2jLa820t/) I have published a dummy example.

Hope help you!